# Java LWJGL VBO using base vertex buffer and height array

Tags: java, opengl, rendering, vbo

I'm having simple problem that I hope to reslove. I have multiple chunks(64x64) with  1d array of all the vertex heights.Since I'm rendering about 100 of them in same time I wonder if I could use a base Vertex Float Buffer and apply dinamicly all the heights as an array.In dynamicly I'm mean the openGL change all the height(y) values while drawing each Vertex. Or is there any more optimized way to do that than overriding all the Buffer values for every chunk?
Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each chunk you can create one VBO as each chunk is different to others (Normally), render the values of the vbo and take a deeper look at the shader pipeline. One VBo is normally holding one mesh. You can change the values of a VBO but this is very expensive. If you create one VBO and change the values for each chunk, this will be incredibly slow. Better create one VBO per chunk, make frustrum culling that you only render the chunks visible to the camera (and apply some other improvements).

For your question of manipulation the hight of a vertex: Take a look at the openGL VertexShader.

I assume that you try to render something using voxel so you may take a look at this tut: https://sites.google.com/site/letsmakeavoxelengine/

It is not finished yet but the ideas are good.

Comment: Hmm, I'm doing normal terrain not cubed, I kind of suspected VertexShaders but I have no exp. with GPU processing so I hoped for another solution.Anyway thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: There is still the old way to do it using the fixed pipeline matrix stack, but as this is the old way I highly recommend to take a deeper look at vertex and fragment shader with the programmable pipeline. VertexShader and are executed per Vertex you want to render and Fragment Shader per pixel on the screen. You process each vertex, the most basic operation is to multiplay the vertex with the model, the view and the projection matrix.

Comment: Already watched some videos and got the basic idea. Thank you